# Не получается запустить с помощью события, строку в методе void

Tags: c#, mvvm, события, делегаты

возникла ситуация, именно через void не получается запустить программу, а вернее не понимаю, как это сделать.

```
 delegate void MyEventHandler();
class MyEvent
{
    public event MyEventHandler SomeEvent;
    public void OnSomeEvent()
    {
        SomeEvent?.Invoke();
    }
}
public class EventShow
{
    public void Handler()
    {
        String.Format("Событие получено объектом класса EventDemo");
    }
}
public class Model
{
    string s; public string S { get => s; set { s = value; } }

    void Main()
    {
        MyEvent myEvent = new MyEvent();
        myEvent.SomeEvent += DisplayMethod;
        myEvent.OnSomeEvent();
    }
    void DisplayMethod()
    {
        EventShow eventShow = new EventShow();
        **Далее для меня тупиковая ситуация!!!!!**

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Зачем вам отдельный класс для эвента? Обычно вызов `Invoke();` происходит в том классе, который содержит это событие (например у вас есть модель базы данных, вы добавили в базу нечто, модель это отследила и вызвала `Invoke();` у нужного события, тем самым оповестив всех, кто подписался на данное событие). А по поводу вопроса, хм, а что мы должны вам тут сказать? Мы же не знаем чего вы хотите сделать дальше. Наверно `eventShow.Handler();` ?

Comment: Да eventShow.Handler и как раз-таки я начинаю путаться, добавляя тем самым ещё один делегат void с параметром string.                                                                                    
     delegate void DelVoid(string message);              
    EventShow eventShow = new EventShow();
            DelVoid delVoid = eventShow.Handler;                                                                                  
               s += delVoid;

Comment: Естественно на выходе: WpfApp1.Model+DelVoid

Comment: Вы хотите вывести некое значение через события или что? Зачем вам тут делегаты?

Comment: Да это значение в классе EventShow в методе Handler, а именно я хотел его вывести через событие, но как уму не приложу.

Comment: Для подобного есть "аргументы", которые событие принимает/передает. В вашем случае (если вы все же хотите свой делегат), то `delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);`, где `EventArgs` - это ваш класс с параметрами передачи. Но я бы на вашем случае отказался бы от своего делегата, тогда можно сделать вовсе `public event EventHandler<SomeData> SomeEvent;` и в вызове будет уже `SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, SomeData);`. Можно вовсе пойти в `Action`, тогда будет `public event Action<string> SomeEvent;` и вызов `SomeEvent?.Invoke("");`.